# Can open small ASCII file, but not large binary file?

Tags: c++, c, file, c++11, large-files

I am using the below code to open a large (5.1GB) binary file in MSVC on Windows. The machine has plenty of RAM. The problem is the length is being retrieved as zero. However, when I change the file_path to a smaller ASCII file the code works fine.

Why can I not load the large binary file? I prefer this approach as I wanted a pointer to the file contents.

```
FILE * pFile;
uint64_t lSize;
char * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen(file_path, "rb");
if (pFile == NULL) { 
    fputs("File error", stderr); exit(1); 
}

// obtain file size:
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(pFile);                                // RETURNS ZERO
rewind(pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) {
    fputs("Memory error", stderr); exit(2); 
}

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);             // RETURNS ZERO TOO
if (result != lSize) {                               // THIS FAILS
    fputs("Reading error", stderr); exit(3); 
}

/* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */
```

its not the file permissions or anything, they are fine.

Comment: If the value returned by `ftell()` is a 4 byte integer, and so is your `long`, how do you expect this value to represent any number larger than 2 gigabytes? Consult your Microsoft documentation for the proper way to use files that exceed 2 gigabytes in size.

Comment: Use the [second one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx).

Comment: Are you compiling in 32 or 64 bit mode? You'll need to make sure you're compiling in 64 bit mode in order to create a 5.1 GB buffer. (in addition to the `ftell()` issues pointed out by comments above)

Comment: Compiling in 64-bit mode. Changed that long to a uint64_t but it made no difference.

Comment: MSVC++ uses the [LLP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), long stays 32 bits.  Use the second one.

Comment: @HansPassant oh I know, just saying it wasn't the underlying cause.

Comment: @mezamorphic It hasn't been noted yet, but you *assume* your call to `fseek()` worked.  And FWIW, `fseek()`/`ftell()` is not a C Standard-compliant way to get the size of a file.  Binary files do not need to support `fseek(..., SEEK_END);` and the value returned by `ftell()` for a text file is not a meaningful count of bytes.

Comment: Again another nice example showing that one shall always test the outcome of relevant function calls. (`fseek()` here at least).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: what do you mean by "value returned by ftell() for a text file is not a meaningful count of bytes"?

Comment: For extremely large files, you want to replace `ftell` with `_ftelli64`,  that returns a 64-bit type

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Per **7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "For a text stream, **its file position indicator contains unspecified
information**, usable by the
`fseek`
function for returning the file position indicator for the
stream  to  its  position  at  the  time  of  the
`ftell`
call;  **the  difference  between  two  such
return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**"  `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file is non-portable.

Comment: the function: `ftell()` returns a `long int`, NOT a `uint64_t`

Comment: when a system function returns an error condition, it is best to use `perror()` for recording the error on stderr, because the output will include a short statement of why the OS thinks the function failed.

Comment: regarding the call to `malloc()`  1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined as 1 in the standard, and multiplying anything by 1 has no effect on the result.  Suggest remove the case, Suggest remove the expression: `sizeof(char)`

Comment: rather than allocating such a huge chunk of the 'heap'  you might want to consider using `mmap()`

Comment: the language `C` is not the language `C++` and the code is using `C` function calls.  Strongly suggest removing the `c++` and the `c++11` tags

Answer (score 2):

If you allocate 5,1 GB, you'd better be sure that you've compiled your code in 64 bits and run it on a 64 bits windows version.  Ohterwhise, the memory [address space is limited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912(v=vs.85).aspx) to maxi 3 GB on a 32 bits Windows and [4 GB with 32 bits code on a 64 bits Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits).

By the way, [`ftell()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) returns a signed `long`. You have to check that there is no error here (such as an overflow if the OS allows larger file sizes), so that the value is not -1.

**Edit:**

Note that [with MSVC, `long` will currently be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) a 32 bits number even if compiled for 64 bits.  This means that `ftell()` will give you a meaningful result if the filesize if below 2GB (because fo the sign).

You could use non portable OS specific WinAPI function [`GetFileSizeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa364957(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the size of large files in a signed 64 bit number.

`malloc()` takes a `size_t` which is an [unsigned 64 bit number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx). So on this side you're safe.

An alternative would be to use [file mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Second edit**

I looked at your edits about value received for size, which differ of what i expected.  I could reproduce the error on my system, and got a size that was not null, but it was a number much much large than the file.

Looking at [this CERT security recommendation](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek()+and+ftell()+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file), it appeared that the guarantees offered by the standard for `fseek()` in combination with `SEEK_END` are unsufficient and make this a very unsafe approach.

So let's repeast: the saffest way to get the size would be to use the native OS function i.e. `GetFileSizeEx()` on Windows.  There's a workaround on a 64 bit windows: use `_fseeki64()` and `_ftelli64()`:

```
...
if (_fseeki64(pFile, 0, SEEK_END)) {
    fputs("File seek error", stderr); 
    return (1);
}
lSize = _ftelli64(pFile);                            // RETURNS EXACT SIZE
...
```

This worked very well (the initial problem seemed to be linked with the return type which was not large enough).  However keep in mind that it's a workaround, and I fear that there could be other error conditions that could lead to the vulnerability reported by CERT.

Comment: This is Windows 7 64 and I have 32GB of memory. I have previously opened this file using boost memory mapping, but I don't want to use this approach now.

Comment: @mezamorphic But did you compile for 64 bits code (i.e. x64 as target in MSVC configuration manager - this is independent of the OS you're compiling on) ?

Comment: @BoPersson True !  I was wrongly assuming it was unsigned long. I edited accordingly.

Comment: It's not necessary to have a 64-bit executable in order to use 64-bit integer values (like file size and offset). It is also not necessary to be able to allocate over 2GB memory unless you want to load / mmap the whole file at once (which is probably a bad idea anyway).

Comment: @mezamorphic I looked at your edit with the values returned by the functions:  I could reproduce the error and made an edit that should solve your problem.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe that's not what I said:  the 64 bit executable is needed to have a 64 bit address space.  With a 32 bit address space imposed by a 32 bit executable you can't load more than 4GB (please look at links in my answer for official Microsoft statement on the issue).   I don't know the real case that causes OP to load the file at once in memory, so I can't neither agree nor to disagree with your judgement on this approach.

Comment: @Christophe: right, sorry. I didn't realize it was OP's idea to load the whole file and not yours.

Answer (score 1):

The data type long is too small to represent you file size. Use the stat() method (or the  Windows-specific alternative [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946(v=vs.85).aspx)) to read the file size.

Comment: I'd really like to know where the idea to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file comes from.  It's not portable, and it won't work on Windows for large files.  Yet it keeps showing up...

Comment: @AndrewHenle if you can show me the correct way to read a large binary file, so that I have a char* pointer to the contents, others can avoid these bad practices.

Comment: @mezamorphic There's no such thing as "the correct way to read a binary file".  What's the data in the file?  How is it stored?  What are you trying to do with it?  I was lamenting the fact that for some reason `fseek()`/`ftell()` gets taught as a method to find the size of of a file, when in fact it's not portable.  It doesn't even work *at all* on one very popular platform for large files.